# Eloquent Auth - Recovery Password

Tags: laravel, eloquent

He estado intentando realizar un recovery password con un modelo diferente al users que crea laravel por defecto, he desechado muchos ejemplos ya que ninguno me ha sido funcional, alguien me podría explicar por favor de qué manera podr+ia realizarlo?

De ante mano muchas gracias